# How to send data from Android(java) to web app and vice-versa while app is running

Tags: android, firebase, api, vue.js, web-applications

I wrapped a Vue js web app using android to make it TWA(Trusted Web App).

Now I want to send `firebase_token` and other data from the Android part to the webapp in TWA. As all the API's are on a web app and I don't want to call any API in Android.

In WebView we can send data from Android to the webapp using `"WebViewController.evaluateJavascript()"` but I don't know how can i send data from my Android(java) to web app.

Answer (score 0):

To send data from Android to a TWA, you can use the WebMessagePort API. The WebMessagePort API allows you to create a channel between the Android app and the TWA. You can then use this channel to send data back and forth between the two applications.

To use the WebMessagePort API, you first need to create a WebMessagePort object in your Android app. You can do this using the createWebMessagePort() method. Once you have created a WebMessagePort object, you can then send data to the TWA by calling the postMessage() method on the WebMessagePort object.

The following code shows how to send data from Android to a TWA using the WebMessagePort API:

```
import android.webkit.WebMessagePort;
```

public class MainActivity {

```
private WebMessagePort mPort;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create a WebMessagePort object.
    mPort = new WebMessagePort();

    // Create a new thread to send data to the TWA.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Send data to the TWA.
            mPort.postMessage("Hello, TWA!");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

In the TWA, you can receive data from Android by listening for the message event on the WebMessagePort object. The message event will be fired whenever data is sent from Android to the TWA.

The following code shows how to receive data from Android in a TWA:

```
    const port = new WebMessagePort();

port.addEventListener("message", event => {
    // Handle the message event.
    const message = event.data;

    console.log(message);
});
```

When the message event is fired, the data property of the event object will contain the data that was sent from Android. You can then use this data to perform any actions that you need to do.

The WebMessagePort API is a powerful tool that can be used to send data between Android and a TWA. By using this API, you can easily communicate between the two applications and share data with each other.